# Useless "no" errors when writing Prolog sorting queries

Tags: sorting, prolog

I tried to write a Prolog query that would sort a given list. Tried two different attempts so far, both attempting to implement insertion sort, but I am unsure why each one failed. Currently using GNU Prolog version 1.5.0 (64 Bits).

Attempt 1: (tried to the insertion and the sorting both in the same query. Very imperative)

```
% Use: sortz([1,3,2], What). or sortz([1,3,2], [], What).
% Attempt to use insertion sort, not sure what's wrong.
% Result will be the last parameter when first element is empty, thus all elements will have been sorted into the second list
sortz([], Sorted, Sorted).
% If there is only 1 value, it is sorted
sortz([Head|Tail], [], Result) :- sortz(Tail, Head, Result).
% Upon encountering the first element smaller or equal to Head, insert Head at that location
sortz([Head|Tail], [SortedHead|SortedTail], Result) :- Head =< SortedHead, sortz(Tail, [Head|[SortedHead|SortedTail]], Result).
% If Head is bigger than current SortedHead, get the result of sorting Head with SortedTail, then continue sorting
sortz([Head|Tail], [SortedHead|SortedTail], Result) :- Head > SortedHead, sortz([Head], SortedTail, SortedRest), sortz(Tail, [SortedHead|SortedRest], Result).
% Shortcut
sortz(List, Result) :- sortz(List, [], Result).
```

Running `sortz([1,3,2], What).` and `sortz([1,3,2], [], What).` both return "no".

Attempt 2:

```
% Shortcut
insertionsort(List, Result) :- insertionsort(List, [], Result).
% Base case. Result will be the last parameter when first element is empty, thus all elements will have been sorted into the second list
insertionsort([], Result, Result).
insertionsort([Head|Tail], Acc, Result) :- insert(Head, Acc, Inter), insertionsort(Tail, Inter, Result).

% Base case
insert([], Result, Result).
% If X is smaller or equal to Head, insert X before Head
insert(X, [Head|Tail], Inter) :- X =< Head, insert([], [X|[Head|Tail]], Inter).
% If X is greater, insert X into the Tail, then append the sorted list onto head
insert(X, [Head|Tail], Inter) :- X > Head, insert(X, Tail, Sortedrest), insert([], [Head|Sortedrest], Inter).
% Base case
insert(X, [], [X]).
```

Running `insertionsort([1,3,2], What).` and `insertionsort([1,3,2], [], What).` both return "What = [1,2,3] ?" first, but upon entering ";", I get "uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,[]/0),(=<)/2)".

Would appreciate any insight as to why these two code samples are wrong. I have already found working examples of sorts elsewhere, but I'm just stuck on why Attempt 1 in particular isn't working. Probably missing a case or two somewhere but I'm not sure how to debug Prolog's "no"s...

Comment: Why write a non-trivial program, get confused & stuck, and then put no effort into learning how to *debug* the program? Should firstly learn how to debug - see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugoverview and its subpages.

Comment: An example of a merge sort: https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/w0hfx2/comment/igfpkft/

Answer (score 3):

Looking at attempt 1 (using swi-prolog):

```
?- trace, sortz([2,1,3], S).
   Call: (11) sortz([2, 1, 3], _13888) ? creep
   Unify: (11) sortz([2, 1, 3], _13888)
   Call: (12) sortz([2, 1, 3], [], _13888) ? creep
   Unify: (12) sortz([2, 1, 3], [], _13888)
   Call: (13) sortz([1, 3], 2, _13888) ? creep
   Fail: (13) sortz([1, 3], 2, _13888) ? creep
```

That is wrong, because the 2nd argument should be a list, i.e. `[2]` instead of `2`.

Replace the one line to be:

```
sortz([Head|Tail], [], Result) :- sortz(Tail, [Head], Result).
```

... and then it works.